# Unable to complete operation in Parks Finder?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-local-government

So I've downloaded, setup, and configured the [ParksFinder web application](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e0b7b8889be24b60aed3455331eb25a6) from ESRI. It took some tweaking and it's finally [up and running](http://maps.cityoftulsa.org/ParksFinder/). But I am having issues that need to be resolved before this site goes live.

I've reduced the Parks listing down to 5 parks in the database because I thought that might be part of a problem I am having.

Whenever I click on one of the Parks, I get the error message, "Unable to complete operation." The icons for Activities do not show up, the URL for the park is not shrunk down to a "More Info" link, and there is no way to add photos? I'm lost.

When I check Chrome's Javascript Console I get something like this...
0: "Error in querying feature attachments."
1: "Layer or Table with ID: 0 does not support Attachments."

I've checked the LocalGovernment DB and there are a Park__ATTACH and a Park__ATTACHREL tables.

Comment: there is a default bug in config.txt http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40287 for a workaround

Comment: Your URL is working for me now - did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the fact that my Local Government SDE Geodatabase was imported from an XML Workspace. Those *__ATTACH tables were generated from the XML.

I went in, deleted the Park__ATTACH (which auto-deleted the Park_ATTACHREL table) and then went to Catalog > Local Government SDE > ReferenceData > Parks and right clicked 'Create Attachment' which re-generated those __ATTACH tables and voila... it works.